# ThespianCluster creates tons of empty json log files

Tags: f#, mbrace

I'm running a local ThespianCluster from F# interactive and having the temp folder blowing up (Windows 10).
Each worker creates tons of empty json log files on name like:

"*logs-20160310T213935259Z.json*"

at more than 1000/min rate in folders like:

"*%PATH%\mbrace-uuid3c64f8b9-3f8c-4b51-a1e4-1ecb76b1535d\systemLogs--29760*".

I tried to change the loglevel for the cluster and using different logger but it doen't have any effect on the problem at all.

Is it my incorrect setup or some kind of an expected behaviour please?
Many thanks in advance.

**UPD:** Raised an issue with MBrace guys and them got it very quickly fixed and released 1.1.3 nugets. Thanks MBrace!